# Can Twitter access tokens from Login be used for Search API?

Tags: ruby, twitter

While reading the Twitter documentation, I got the sense that depending on type of authorization, you have different access to the API.

My question: If I am doing OAuth authorization for Twitter login, can those access tokens I get back be used to make search API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what different auth levels you have in mind, but as far as I remember most of Twitter API calls (that require auth) have "Requires user context" annotation, but it looks like there is no distinction between different levels (at least nothing about restricting search API)

Also to do search you don't really need auth tokens. You can access search endpoint via http://search.twitter.com/search.json